# Change name of a post type without losing posts

Tags: mysql, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have made a site that uses custom posts types for a projects section.

I need to change the post type from 'projects' to 'galleries' but as I have already uploaded a bunch of projects was wondering how I would do this with as little as possible hassle (I do not want to have to re-upload all the images and text etc)

I found a few articles that tell me to do a SQL query to rename the posts

```
UPDATE  `wp_posts` 
    SET  `post_type` =  '<new post type name>' 
    WHERE  `post_type` = '<old post type name>';
```

And this one for the taxonomy

```
UPDATE  `wp_term_taxonomy` 
    SET  `taxonomy` =  '<new taxonomy name>' 
    WHERE  `taxonomy` = '<old taxonomy name>';
```

I just have no idea what I am supposed to do with this code. If it is SQL do I run it in a php file or is there some sort of 'terminal' that can be found in the WP dashboard or cPanel of my site?

Below is how I created my post type (Not sure if this helps)

```
function create_my_post_types() {
    //projects 
    register_post_type(
      'Projects', array('label' => 'Projects','description' => '','public' => true,'show_ui' => true,'show_in_menu' => true, 'menu_position' => 8,'capability_type' => 'post','hierarchical' => false,'rewrite' => array('slug' => '','with_front' => '0'),'query_var' => true,'exclude_from_search' => false,'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail'),'taxonomies' => array('category',),'labels' => array (
      'name' => 'Projects',
      'singular_name' => 'Project',
      'menu_name' => 'Projects',
      'add_new' => 'Add New Project',
      'add_new_item' => 'Add New Project',
      'edit' => 'Edit',
      'edit_item' => 'Edit Project',
      'new_item' => 'New Project',
      'view' => 'View Project',
      'view_item' => 'View Project',
      'search_items' => 'Search Projects',
      'not_found' => 'No Projects Found',
      'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Projects Found in Trash',
      'parent' => 'Parent Projects',
    ),) );  

} // end create_my_post_types
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have CPanel access, you can look for PHPMyAdmin and run the SQL code there.

1. Go to PHPMyAdmin.
2. Select your wordpress database from the left.
3. **RECOMMENDED:** Backup your database first, by going to the export tab at the top and doing a quick export.
4. Select "SQL" from the top tabs.
5. Copy your SQL queries in the huge textarea, and click Go.

Hope it works!

Answer (score 2):

It's better to go directly with a plugin:

> #### [Convert Post Types](http://wordpress.org/plugins/convert-post-types/)
>
> This is a utility for converting lots of posts or pages to a custom post type (or vice versa). You can limit the conversion to posts in a single category or children of specific page. You can also assign new taxonomy terms, which will be added to the posts' existing terms.

All the conversion process happens in the function [`bulk_convert_posts()`](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/convert-post-types/tags/1.2.1/convert-post-types.php#L126), using the core functions `wp_update_post` and `wp_set_post_terms`. IMO, you should use WordPress functions to do the conversion, there are quite some steps happening in the `terms` function *before* the MySQL command.

***Do a database backup** before proceeding with this kind of operations.*